# navigator.notification.alert not working in cordova for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova-3

I'm working with cordova framework in iphone....Now,i want to use `navigator.notification.alert`this function.but,i can not use this function..

I've done this following steps.

step 1: In config.xml file

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
<header-file src="CDVNotification.h" />
<source-file src="CDVNotification.m" />
<resource-file src="CDVNotification.bundle" />
<framework src="AudioToolbox.framework" weak="true" />
```

step 2 : I've added AudioToolbox.framework in my project

step 3 : added CDVNotification.h and .m file in plugins folder.

step 4: added notification.js into index.html file.

step 5: then finally,i've done this code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    function onDeviceReady() {

        alert("onDeviceReady");
        navigator.notification.alert('Mesage',
                                     null,
                                     'Title',
                                     'OK')
    }
```

can anyone help me!!!

Comment: which cordova version you are using

Comment: i m using cordova 3.3.0

Comment: @iDev : do u have any soluation?

Comment: please,,tell me..where are my mistakes?

Comment: you want exactly solution for navigator.notification.alert else may i tell alternatively solution for that

Comment: i want exactly solution for navigator.notification.alert

Comment: can u tell me the alternatively solution for that?

Comment: did you get solution for this issue...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the plugin using the CLI

use this command

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively solution

```
window.alert();
```

This global alert. very easy to manage.don't need to added any plugin or anything esle.

Comment: okie..thanks..but its not for my project..i also want to display my project name in alert box..

Comment: while displaying alert box at the top,its display the page name like index.html.....but i want to display my project name instead of page name..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and couldn't solve it but then it him me since Cordova is nothing but a webview based app javascript based solutions will work as well. So I used this js alert plugin called alertify which is beautiful and customizable as to headers,colors etc. and does the job well.

[Javascript Alert Plugiy.](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)